# Unable to connect ESP8266 to WPA2+Enterprise network

Tags: esp8266, wifi, wireless

I am trying to connect ESP8266 module to WPA2+Enterprise network with my ssid, username and password and the latest version supports such connection. I followed [this](https://www.hallgeirholien.no/post/esp8266-eap/) link, and the code:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
extern "C" {
  #include "user_interface.h"
  #include "wpa2_enterprise.h"
}

static const char* ssid = "ssid";
static const char* username = "username";
static const char* password = "password";
const char* host = "host_ip";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
   // Setting ESP into STATION mode only (no AP mode or dual mode)
  wifi_set_opmode(0x01);

  struct station_config wifi_config;

  memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof(wifi_config));
  strcpy((char*)wifi_config.ssid, ssid);

  wifi_station_set_config(&wifi_config);

  wifi_station_clear_cert_key();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_ca_cert();

  wifi_station_set_wpa2_enterprise_auth(1);
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_username((uint8*)username, strlen(username));
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_password((uint8*)password, strlen(password));

  wifi_station_connect();
  Serial.print("Wifi station connect status:");
  Serial.println(wifi_station_get_connect_status());

  // Wait for connection AND IP address from DHCP
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("Not connected");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop()
{
  delay(2000);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Connecting to ssid
Wifi station connect status:1
6
Not connected
6
Not connected
.....
```

Status 6 is  WL_DISCONNECTED,i.e., module is not configured in station mode. I am not able to figure out what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The clear commands are not useful until after you have connected.
I use these commands just before setting user ID and password:

```
wifi_station_set_enterprise_identity((uint8*)username1, strlen(username));
wifi_station_set_enterprise_ca_cert(ca_cert, sizeof(ca_cert));
```

It is necessary that the radius server have `default_eap_type` set to TTLS or PEAP for username/password authentication. Perhaps there is another possibility, but there is a bug in ESP8266 so it does not properly search for supported EAP types.

```
const char* username1 = "anonymous"; //works for me

u8 ca_cert[] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIJAO0ntD34r/+QMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGiMQswCQYD\n"
"VQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UECAwOTm9ydGggQ2Fyb2xpbmExDzANBgNVBAcMBkR1cmhh\n"
"bTEeMBwGA1UECgwVTWl0Y2hlbGwvVHJhbXBlciBJbmMuMR8wHQYJKoZIhvcNAQkB\n"
"FhBidXJ0bXNAZ21haWwuY29tMSgwJgYDVQQDDB9CdXJ0IFNlbGYgQ2VydGlmaWNh\n"
"dGUgQXV0aG9yaXR5MB4XDTE4MDEyMzE1NTgxOFoXDTE4MDMyNDE1NTgxOFowgaIx\n"
"CzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRcwFQYDVQQIDA5Ob3J0aCBDYXJvbGluYTEPMA0GA1UEBwwG\n"
"RHVyaGFtMR4wHAYDVQQKDBVNaXRjaGVsbC9UcmFtcGVyIEluYy4xHzAdBgkqhkiG\n"
"9w0BCQEWEGJ1cnRtc0BnbWFpbC5jb20xKDAmBgNVBAMMH0J1cnQgU2VsZiBDZXJ0\n"
"aWZpY2F0ZSBBdXRob3JpdHkwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIB\n"
"AQC2O2m4JCmqimeztaZ8JasIuZqksrxvCjyWpkykoGzoR6v1/kDSuLgdp7EmtLKN\n"
"vOJPQ2ea0yVvkFf0dQYcgDhNdAsXcqskMOprS+jefzlLQUbU1jTk+AOSiOcmxWT1\n"
"H8uYhSp/1TkkWDM8dVO9RRIQyigVinsJNhdPyUVsTaQh3s29AL8CboixUNZWngOo\n"
"d1+66lwy4N+3hXACJWlurgvc0q7RfqSqfJY/+lugfID0ANpGQqqu1Dq2IXZbLyx9\n"
"roOPpC+fqX2wn5g9+RuA18OY/GPtkHc6clAoiJDGXsTRpffgsI5spdJ26WknbhO/\n"
"3Q2vQJ2Q5m/QvSp55qOM5nevAgMBAAGjggFGMIIBQjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUT3hChU84\n"
"EEXHesDdKOtPqfhrg68wgdcGA1UdIwSBzzCBzIAUT3hChU84EEXHesDdKOtPqfhr\n"
"g6+hgaikgaUwgaIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRcwFQYDVQQIDA5Ob3J0aCBDYXJvbGlu\n"
"YTEPMA0GA1UEBwwGRHVyaGFtMR4wHAYDVQQKDBVNaXRjaGVsbC9UcmFtcGVyIElu\n"
"Yy4xHzAdBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEGJ1cnRtc0BnbWFpbC5jb20xKDAmBgNVBAMMH0J1\n"
"cnQgU2VsZiBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBBdXRob3JpdHmCCQDtJ7Q9+K//kDAPBgNVHRMB\n"
"Af8EBTADAQH/MDYGA1UdHwQvMC0wK6ApoCeGJWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZXhhbXBsZS5v\n"
"cmcvZXhhbXBsZV9jYS5jcmwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBADNmDxddEh1XSo8J\n"
"fanCRuYqngpVFtKCzRNCtQ7aOAPrj6gRMtMAqQhlYmcbxjaVOCboAvJ8evY8x5We\n"
"YU6eIAmg95PlDws8EvcVQhO2ZYcuOHTvdu5Q4Ior0oXaCfqdS35YcPW7pRGprY/x\n"
"w7kbG84FFatpXPuDGQB65haqQ2KXPrILiE/jAKpTu9EBLEEN4uIAuxbB6unARovX\n"
"YoXIQHFc32bZAjihquvs4J7FNkcSr3lJpuv03dryqMB+Qn3G8yM7PFLNL2QyS0Zu\n"
"UbS5kDO7UqbTjtrUDolp5sUNvyrkX5ILYfZeEeaHqAlA20SFqNG7BcTY222NsCft\n"
"yNXqX1c=\n"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

works for me. I have to go back and check whether those `\n`'s are needed.

I think I found the enterprise_identity command important for both TTLS and PEAP, and I found I needed a `ca_cert` to do PEAP but not necessary for TTLS. I am not certain why.